# Feature Grid Layer to cluster features at higher zoom levels in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, indexing

I was wondering if there is a plug in for Leaflet which accomplishes clustering features within a grid layer. Similar to marker clusters this allows for rendering an abstraction of all features with a count of the features within that area. In my case I want to do this for centerlines of a city which is too much to render at higher zoom levels.

The overall end effect is similar to what is seen in the [LA geohub](http://geohub.lacity.org/datasets/d3cd48afaacd4913b923fd98c6591276_36):

[image]

where you need to click the grid till at proper zoom level to render any features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any existing plugins to accomplish this, so you may need to pre-process your data (for example, using the free desktop program [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org)) to calculate the number of features within each grid cell.

1. Create a polygon [grid/fishnet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123446/3112)
2. [Intersect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78836/3112) the road centrelines with the polygon grid
3. [Count](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110930/3112) the number of lines within each polygon

Use the count to symbolise the polygons, as in your example screenshot

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will look into this as it sounds exactly what I need.